# How Many Three-Digits Even Numbers Can Be Formed From 2,4,5

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question:
I was wondering how many $3$-Digits Even Numbers can be formed from $2,4,5$ ?

My Approach:
If we take even number $2$ at extreme right _ _ $2$ then 2 permutations can formed from remaining numbers i.e ($4,5$), similarly if we take $4$ at extreme right _ _ $4$ then again 2 permutations will be formed. So,

$2!+2!=6$

Is my answer correct? because according to my teacher it should be 18.

Conclusion:
Help will be highly appreciated and i want the clear method to solve questions of this kind in which any number digits either even or odd can be formed using any given numbers.

P.S.(Sorry for Bad English)

Thanks,

Comment: Are numbers like $222$ allowed? or do all three digits have to be different?

Comment: If you have to use each number exactly once, then aren't the only answers $542,452,524,254$?  So, $4$, not $6$.  But of course $18$ appears to indicate that you can use each number repeatedly or not at all.

Comment: @user574848 ,  well there is no condition in the question that says that no repetation is allowed so i think we are allowed repitition i guess ..... but the answer is $18$ how do i get $18$ ..... or my Maths teacher is wrong (lol jk).

Comment: @lulu thanks for pointing out my mistake, so exactly how can i achieve $18-numbers$?

Comment: Well, how many options are there for the leftmost digit?  How many for the middle digit?  How many for the rightmost?

Comment: @lulu , $3$ Options for left most digits, $3$ options for middle digits and $2$ options for right most digits.

Comment: Ok, and $3\times 3\times 2=?$

Comment: $18$  thanks man your a real life saver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's the number is $\,\overline{abc} \,$ with $ a,b,c \in \{ 2,4,5\} $ and $c\in \{2,4\}$ ( because $\,c\,$ is the even number).We have 
a has three choices, b has three choices and c has two choices. Therefore, we have $3*3*2=18 $ numbers satisfies the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot! @lulu already solved my problem but your answer made it more clear.